# Increase and decrease a data attar depending on the size

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I currently hhave this http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/1/

What's the best way to decrease the data attribute data-size when you remove a div? so basically the data-size increases when you add fields and decreases when you remove fields.
my html

```
<ul id="variants"> 
    <a href="#" class="add_options" data-id="70281696560900">Add more </a>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `data-size`, do you mean the `size` attribute on the text field?

Comment: You fiddle is not working

Comment: There's not `data-size` in the code you posted or in the jsfiddle, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong one. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="variants" data-size="0">
  <a href="#" class="add_options" data-id="70281696560900">Add more </a>
</ul>
Number of rows: <span id="count">0</span>
```

JS:

```
$('.add_options').on('click', function () {
    $('#variants').append('<div class="some_id"><input type="text" id="prop_name" class="prop_name" placeholder="Property name"><a href="#" class="remover">Remove</a></div>');
    var size = parseInt($('#variants').attr("data-size"), 10) + 1;
    $('#variants').attr("data-size", size);
    $("#count").text(size);
});
$('#variants').on('click', '.remover', function () {
    $(this).closest('.some_id').hide();
    var size = parseInt($('#variants').attr("data-size"), 10) - 1;
    $('#variants').attr("data-size", size);
    $("#count").text(size);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mDfQT/10/)

Comment: Your fiddle uses the same ID `some_id` for every DIV it adds. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: `.size()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, use `.length` instead. See http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Sorry i sort of wrote it on there, i used nesting( id-> class) in the real thing. The adding part increases the data-size but the decreasing is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You need to use delegation for your remover click handler, because the elements are added dynamically after the handler is established.

Comment: Another problem with your code: The "Remove" button just hides the DIV, it doesn't actually remove it. So it's counted in `.size()`. So every time you add an element, `data-size` is bumped back up to include the removed rows.

Comment: Yh again in the real thing i used $(document).on('click','.remove_variants', function(){, Sorry i just wrote a quick code to try to explain what i wanted to achieve. Doing the same thing i did for the add to the remove works only when i use.remove(), i understand .hide gives it a display none thats why i was trying to replicate the remove by subtracting 1. Sorry it's so confusing :) I'll try your code using -1, What does the 10 in the parseint param signify?

Comment: Updated answer with rewritten version of your fiddle that works.

Comment: 10 is the radix to parse in, since the default is browser-dependent.

Comment: The problem is that you subtract 1 when hiding, but you don't add 1 when adding. You could use `$(".variants:visible").length` to get the number of visible divs.